# Evaluate the following 2nd kind line integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, line-integrals

$$\int _{\gamma }\:\left(x+y\right)dx-\left(x-y\right)dy\:$$ $$\:\gamma \::\:y=1-\left|1-x\right|$$ $$\:x\in \left[0,2\right]$$

Is this way of solving it correct? I have trouble figuring out how to parameterize the path, so I am not sure if it's alright this way

[image] where O(0,0) ; A(1,1) ; B(2,0)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You only need to go from $O$ to $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have edited, I was planning to ask 2 questions and I swapped them wrongly. I apologize!

Comment: Again, I'd suggest a better title @tryingtosolvethispain

Comment: I tried, it's a bit hard for me since I haven't used english for math so I don't know a lot of words, I tried to translate my question from my native language into english so that's why it turned out like that, also most of my questions are just evaluate,etc. I have no idea what title to put honestly... I was thinking of Line integral of... or Line integral between ... but my vocabulary is lacking so I legit stopped having ideas there.

Comment: You should put in title what exactly is special about this integral , so if someone searched for an example later they can find this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first leg can simply have $x=t, y=t, 0 \leq t \leq 1$.
The second leg can be $x = t, y = 2-t, 1 \leq t \leq 2$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the quick reply I also read the comment and I was thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out a way to 'avoid' doing some integrals:

$$I=\int_{\gamma} (x+y) dx -(x-y) dy = \int_{\gamma} x dx  + y dy + \int_{\gamma} ydx -x dy = 
 \int_{\gamma} d(xy) -\int_{\gamma}x^2 d( \frac{y}{x})= (xy)|_{\gamma} - \frac{y}{x} x^2|_{\gamma} +\int_{\gamma} 2ydx $$

Ultimately:

$$ I =  2 \int_{\gamma} y dx$$

Which is just area under curve, also area of the triangle which is $1$ , hence the final answer is $I=2$